# How do I add bitlocker support commands to winpe?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bitlocker

Tried following this tutorial https://4sysops.com/archives/unlock-bitlocker-under-windows-pe/

But when I boot up my winpe image and try to run `manage-bde` I can `"manage-bde is not recognized..."`

Here are the packages I added to my Windows 10 x64 winpe (booting to an x64 windows 10 PC):

```
winpe-wmi.cab
winpe-scripting.cab
WinPE-PowerShell.cab
winpe-SecureBootCmdlets.cab
winpe-SecureBootStartup.cab
```

Comment: Make sure you aren't using Windows 10 Home. It doesn't support BitLocker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dude had the same problem:
http://www.eightforums.com/system-security/46543-how-enable-bitlocker-support-unlock-drive-winpe-5-a.html

I didn't create a separate subfolder like he did, but I can confirm this worked for me with the win10 PE image:

> 8) Final solution was to create a subdirectory called "BitLocker" in
>   \Windows\System32, then copy
>   C:\Windows\System32\manage-bde.exe and C:\Windows\System32\en-US\ into
>   it. Then I performed the Commit to finalize and create my WinPE image.
>
> 9) Upon booting my WinPE environment, in the Command Prompt, I change
>   to the "BitLocker" directory and run  manage-bde.exe from there to
>   unlock my BitLocker volumes. No errors.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work, you have to load the necessary CAB files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs.  Once those are loaded, you have to load the same CAB files from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us folder.  Once I loaded both instances of the CAB files, the commands worked in WinPE.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to download Windows Media Creation tool 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

boot and start in the troubleshooting menu the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the
"Windows kits"/"Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment" Command prompt (Run as Admin)

Create a BuildWinPE.CMD with the contents below and run it. It will even create an ISO:

---

```
@echo Copies winpe env to C:\WinPE_x64\
@Pause
copype.cmd amd64 C:\WinPE_x64
@echo Mounts winpe to C:\WinPE_x64\mount
@Pause
Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"C:\WinPE_x64\media\sources\boot.wim" /Index:1 /MountDir:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount"
@echo Install WMI, .NET, Bitlocker & TPM support
@Pause
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /Add-Package /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-WMI.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-WMI_en-us.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /Add-Package /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-NetFx.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-NetFx_en-us.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-FMAPI.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-SecureStartup.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-SecureStartup_en-us.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-EnhancedStorage.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-EnhancedStorage_en-us.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-Scripting.cab"
Dism /Image:"C:\WinPE_x64\mount" /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-Scripting_en-us.cab"
@echo Continue when done
@Pause
dism /unmount-wim /mountdir:"C:\WinPE_x64\MOUNT" /commit
MakeWinPEMedia /ISO /f C:\WinPE_x64 C:\WinPE_x64\WinPE_USMToffline.iso
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The following commands helped me, you'll have to adapt to make it work for you.

1. Mount the image file in your your `WinPE` directory.

   ```
   Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"C:\winpe_x86\media\sources\boot.wim" /index:1 /MountDir:"C:\winpe_x86\mount"
   ```
2. Add the packages `WinPE-WMI`, `WinPE-SecureStartup`, `WinPE-EnhancedStorage` and `WinPE-Scripting`. I don't know which package provides the `manage-bde` executable, but one of those does. Below I show the command for installation of `WinPE-SecureStartup` startup only. Please adapt it for others.

   ```
   Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_x86\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\x86\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-SecureStartup.cab"
   ```
3. For the support pack to work, you need to also install at least one language pack for the associated package. Here I show an example of EN-GB version of the `SecureStartup` pack.

   ```
   Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_x86\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\x86\WinPE_OCs\en-gb\WinPE-SecureStartup_en-gb.cab"
   ```
4. Unmount and commit your packages.

   ```
   dism /unmount-wim /mountdir:"C:\WinPE_x86\MOUNT" /commit
   ```
5. Make a bootable version of the image.

   ```
   MakeWinPEMedia.cmd  /UFD C:\winpe_x86 E:
   ```

   Note: `MakeWinPEMedia` can only be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment` or similar.
6. Change BIOS to legacy mode if needed.